# MS Graph SDK C# - Get all Tasks within a Plan

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to obtain all Tasks (title or whatever) from a certain plan.

Currently, the code I have just returns the plans I am part of or the tasks assigned to me, but I would also like to retrieve the Tasks that are within a {lan that are not assigned.

```
var plans = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Planner
    .Plans
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

foreach (var plan in plans)
{
    //works
    Console.WriteLine(plan.Title);
    Console.WriteLine(plan.Id);

    //does not work
    Console.WriteLine(plan.Tasks);
    Console.WriteLine(plan.Tasks.Count);
}

var tasks = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Planner
    .Tasks
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.Title);
}
```

Withing the part of the code where `//does not work` are the two lines that do not work (even if used 1 at a time)

Can't think of a way to get the unassigned tasks. Tried to remove the `.Me` part, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try adding Expand to the initial request `var plans = await graphServiceClient.Me.Planner.Plans.Request().Expand("Tasks").GetAsync();`

Comment: Now it does not even return the title of the plan, but thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK won't automatically populate `plan.Tasks` which is why they're showing up as null. You'll need to request them separately.

To do that, you first need to note the difference between getting a *list* of your plans (`/me/planner/plans/`), a *single* plan (`/planner/plans/{id}`) and the *tasks within a single plan* (`/planner/plans/{id}/tasks`).

So first you need to fetch the list of plans, then retrieve the tasks as you iterate over the plans:

```
var plans = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Planner
    .Plans
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

foreach (var plan in plans)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{plan.Title} ({plan.Id})");

    var tasks = await graphServiceClient
        .Planner
        .Plans[plan.Id]
        .Tasks
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{task.Title} ({task.Id})");
    }
}
```